# Fix a container div on scroll of other div

Tags: jquery, css, fixed, scrolltop

I am facing issues making a container div position fixed when scrolling to a certain point without sacrificing the rest of my css layout.

I tried to make both the wrapper profile_overview and the indicators positioned fixed when scrolling down. However, every time the respective CSS class is added the layout is destroyed.

```js
$(".profile_right").scroll(function() {
        if ($(".profile_right").scrollTop() <= 1) {
           $('.profile_overview').removeClass('adjust_height_profile');
        } else {
            $('.profile_overview').addClass('adjust_height_profile');
        }
    });
```

```css
html {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}


::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* Styling of the main wrapper + setting up the left and right side of the user.php page */
.main_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

/*
*===========================================
*/

/* Left hand side navigation items */
.nav_items_left {
  width: 5%;
  height: 100vh;
  float: left;
  background-color: green;
}

/*
*===========================================
*/

/* Right hand side profile content */
.profile_right {
  width: 95%;
  height: 100vh;
  float: right;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.header_profiles {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5vh;
}

/*
*===========================================
*/

.profile_overview {
  margin-top: 2%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

.adjust_height_profile {
  height: 10vh;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  position: fixed;
}

.profile_container {
  width: 22.5%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Active indicator */
.active_indicator {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.5vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 1% 0 1% 0;
}

.active_profile_indicator {
  width: 22.5%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="DE">
<head>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<!-- Wrapper around navigation items and profile overview -->
<div class="main_wrapper">

    <!-- Nav items positioned on the left hand side -->
    <div class="nav_items_left">

    </div>


    <!-- Profiles positioned on the right hand side -->
    <div class="profile_right">

        <div class="header_profiles">
          
        </div>


        <!-- ========================================= -->

        <!-- Different blocks -->

        <main>

            <div class="profile_overview">

                <!-- Block 1 -->
                <div class="profile_container">
                </div>

                <!-- Block 2 -->
                <div class="profile_container">
                </div>

                <!-- Block 3 -->
                <div class="profile_container">
                </div>

                <!-- Block 4 -->
                <div class="profile_container">
                </div>

            </div>

            <!-- ========================================= -->

            <!-- Show which profile is active -->
            <div class="active_indicator">
                <div class="active_profile_indicator"></div>
                <div class="active_profile_indicator"></div>
                <div class="active_profile_indicator"></div>
                <div class="active_profile_indicator"></div>
            </div>
            
            <!-- ======================================== --> 
            
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            
           
        </main>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The goal is to decrease the height of the 4 blocks on the right-hand side triggered by the scrolling and simultaneously make them positioned fixed at the top of the screen. Same applies to the indicators underneath which should be fixed as well.

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Yes, sorry for that comment, i mistaken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the layout "breaks" is because setting the header to `fixed` positioning takes it out of normal layout. Just like `absolute` positioning, that means that the space it used to take up in the document is removed, so you'll see the  `<p>test</p>` elements move up into that empty space when the `adjust_height_profile` class is added.

The most straightforward solution is to apply `position: fixed` to the profile_overview header always, and add margin to the element following it. However, you'll still see content "scrolling" behind the header, because you've applied a top margin and have not specified a background color.  That means as the non-fixed content scrolls it will show through the header.  You'll need to affix the header to the top of the container and replace  `margin-top: 2%` with `padding-top: 2%`;

Is there a reason your active_indicator container isn't part of the profile_overview header?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <style>
    html {
      overflow-y: hidden;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    
    body {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      background-color: transparent;
      font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    }
    
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
      display: none;
    }
    /* Styling of the main wrapper + setting up the left and right side of the user.php page */
    
    .main_wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    /*
*===========================================
*/
    /* Left hand side navigation items */
    
    .nav_items_left {
      width: 5%;
      height: 100vh;
      float: left;
      background-color: green;
    }
    /*
*===========================================
*/
    /* Right hand side profile content */
    
    .profile_right {
      width: 95%;
      height: 100vh;
      float: right;
      background-color: yellow;
      overflow: scroll;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    
    .header_profiles {
      width: 100%;
      height: 5vh;
    }
    /*
*===========================================
*/
    
    .profile_overview {
      width: 100%;
      height: 40vh;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
      transition-delay: .5s;
      /* This is changed */
      padding-top: 2%;
      /* margin-top: 2%; */
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      background-color: yellow;
    }
    
    .adjust_height_profile {
      height: 10vh;
      transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
      /*position: fixed;*/
    }
    
    .profile_container {
      width: 22.5%;
      height: 100%;
      border-radius: 8px;
      background-color: white;
      box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    /* Active indicator */
    
    .active_indicator {
      width: 100%;
      height: 0.5vh;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      margin: 1% 0 1% 0;
    }
    
    .active_profile_indicator {
      width: 22.5%;
      background-color: lightgrey;
      border-radius: 8px;
    }
    /* This is added */
    
    .content {
      margin-top: 40vh;
    }
    
    .adjust_height_profile+.content {
      margin-top: 10vh;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Wrapper around navigation items and profile overview -->
  <div class="main_wrapper">

    <!-- Nav items positioned on the left hand side -->
    <div class="nav_items_left">

    </div>


    <!-- Profiles positioned on the right hand side -->
    <div class="profile_right">

      <div class="header_profiles">

      </div>


      <!-- ========================================= -->

      <!-- Different blocks -->

      <main>

        <div class="profile_overview">

          <!-- Block 1 -->
          <div class="profile_container">
          </div>

          <!-- Block 2 -->
          <div class="profile_container">
          </div>

          <!-- Block 3 -->
          <div class="profile_container">
          </div>

          <!-- Block 4 -->
          <div class="profile_container">
          </div>

        </div>

        <!-- ========================================= -->

        <!-- Show which profile is active -->
        <div class="active_indicator">
          <div class="active_profile_indicator"></div>
          <div class="active_profile_indicator"></div>
          <div class="active_profile_indicator"></div>
          <div class="active_profile_indicator"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- ======================================== -->
        <div class="content">
          <p>test 1</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
        </div>

      </main>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>

<script>
  $(".profile_right").scroll(function() {
    if ($(".profile_right").scrollTop() <= 1) {
      $('.profile_overview').removeClass('adjust_height_profile');
    } else {
      $('.profile_overview').addClass('adjust_height_profile');
    }
  });
</script>
```